# Is there a way to bookmark custom commands in ubntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I want a way to bookmark custom commands, so that the next time when i want to execute a command, I should type only the bookmark-name instead of the big line of command.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias

Answer (score 1):

Just add bash aliases in your `$:~/.bashrc` or `$:~/.bash_aliases`. You can see here : https://askubuntu.com/a/17537/145261 or https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-useful-bash-aliases-and-functions